# Linq using TakeWhile in a query

Tags: c#, linq, console

Hi i just started learning linq and have been trying to understand the TakeWhile usage

here i have tried something like this

```
 using (  var db = new OrchestrateDataEntities())
        {


            var y = db.Set<Rulebook_Mapping>();
            var xyz = y.TakeWhile(x => x.ID == 2).AsQueryable();
            foreach (var item in xyz)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ID);


            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and then comes the error

```
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ConFW.Rulebook_Mapping] TakeWhile[Rulebook_Mapping](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ConFW.Rulebook_Mapping], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConFW.Rulebook_Mapping,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: just curious why do you need .AsQueryable()

Comment: It havent worked without that and havent worked with that too though just used it

Answer (score 2):

Check supported and unsupported methods in LINQ to Entity at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/01/02/linq-to-entity-skip-and-take-method-does-not-work.aspx. Then open paging method page, you will see that TakeWhile is not supported (at the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

[qxg is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635919/2055187), TakeWhile is not implemented by EF, but you can use it in LINQ to Object.

Old code:

```
var y = db.Set<Rulebook_Mapping>();
```

New code:

```
var y = db.Set<Rulebook_Mapping>().ToList();
```

New code should fix the error, it brings all records in RuleBook_Mapping table to local memory, if possible add where filter before ToList() will help the performance.